# Implications for deleting files using WSL

Tags: filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Are there any downfalls to using WSL to delete files (e.g. `rm someFile`) on the regular Windows file system (`mnt/c`)? Likewise, is there a downfall to using Windows to delete (for example by 'right click + delete') files generated by a WSL script (for example `make`) in `mnt/c`?

I am curious because from what I understand, Linux uses a different file system (ext4) than Windows (NTFS). Do they both handle a '*delete*' the same way? What does WSL use when working in `mnt/c`?

I have been assuming that either approach deletes the file properly (i.e. frees up space in disk appropriately).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because WSL is not Unix/Linux.

Comment: @IporSircer ... but there's already a tag on this site ([windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux)) precisely for this kind of question... o.0?

Comment: Either approach deletes the file properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No downfalls; WSL is an API in NT for GNU etc, not Linux; so Linux file systems are not supported.